# Working and editing Woocommerce Hooks to change functionalities

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm working with *WooCommerce* and I'm changing some functionalities in my home page.

My theme uses "*Woocommerce Hooks*" but I only see where calls the function. What I need is to find that function and change it.

In my case I saw that the code I want to change is in "**/plugin/component/wc_product.php**" and there I see this piece of code:

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if( "default" == $tpvc_wc_product_style ) : ?>
            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content-product' ); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content-product', 'alt' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</ul>
```

But when I go to "**/theme/woocommerce/content-product.php**" I only see this code:

```
<li <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="product-inner">
    <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

Where are *Woocommerce Hooks* functions deployed? Where are that **do_action()** functions so I can edit them?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks!! But this help me to find the hook, and I've already found it. I know that it's in **templates/content-product.php** and **includes/wc-template-hooks.php ** but I need to change how it works. I need to enter inside that action and edit it. Is this possible?

Comment: `content-product.php` is loaded in `archives-product.php`… In templates `do_action()` are the hooks entry points where other templates hook there or they are entry points for your custom functions: You can use `add_action` to hook your custom functions in that hooks. You can use `remove_action()` to removed hooked templates or functions in that entry points. You have also a lot of hooks in core files,where you can insert code using `add_action()`… This are wordpress native hook functions. you can also use `add_filter()` or `remove_filter()`…